# Can a Boggart Kiss someone as a Dementor?

Tags: harry-potter, dementors

If someone's boggart was a Dementor, could they get Kissed and lose their soul?

Related: [Would a boggart-basilisk kill someone?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/43058/would-a-boggart-basilisk-kill-someone)

Comment: Is there any reason why you think the answer would be any different from the other question?

Comment: [This answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/43064/30390) on the question you linked answers your question for you (some of the other answers talk about dementors too).

Comment: sadly the accepted answer from the related question is based purely on speculation, i think that alexwlchan's answer does however accurately answer the question.

Answer (score 5):

I would say that no, a boggart kiss would not drain the soul of a person.

While Harry experienced some of the dementor feelings from the boggart, I think we can tell that they're not fully functional from a different event. When the dementor turned into a full moon if it had the complete effects of the full moon Lupin would have immediately started turning into a werewolf. However since that wasn't the case I believe the boggart's imitation is essentially incomplete.

Comment: It's not explicitly said that the full moon *causes* the transformation. Perhaps it's just a sign that coincides with the transformation.

Comment: no it is explicit, the full moon is what causes the transformation.

Comment: in book 3, lupin is walking out with sirius harry and wormtail and the get outside, and the book im pretty sure says and the clouds cleared revealing the full moon, and lupin immediately falls over and starts to change. we know they will change without seeing the moon, during the full moon, seeing the moon itself speed up the process and in a mater of seconds he was transforming.

Comment: This has been discussed previously: [Do werewolves in Harry Potter only transform under moonlight?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/9980/5184), [What triggers a lycanthropic change in the Potterverse?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/15350/5184), [Can werewolves turn outside of the Full Moon in Harry Potter?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/38600/5184)

Comment: But maybe it also has to be the right time of the month, and even if you see the moon, it won't do anything unless it's the right time.

Comment: The answer to http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/15353/16518 gives another reason for the boggart-moon not working; it was day.

Comment: the first line of her answer though is that she believe the moon is the main cause, in her answer it shows that a full moon cannot naturally occur during the day, therefor they never transform in the day purly because the moon is never out.